# Using subquery in Doctrine 1.2

Tags: doctrine, subquery, doctrine-1.2

I'm having alot of trouble using a subquery in an update statement in doctrine 1.2
I want to set a field to the result of a subquery, but it seems impossible.
This is what i tried sofar.

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Users_Model_Book b');    
$subSelect = $query->createSubquery()->select('ROUND(SUM(br.rating) / COUNT(br.id))')->from('b.BookRating')->where('b.BookRating.book_id = b.id');
$query->update()->set('bookrating', '('.$subSelect->getDql().')')->where('b.id = ?', $this->id)->getRawSql();
```

**Will give 'Unknown component alias br'**

```
    $q = new Doctrine_RawSql();
    $q  ->addComponent('b', 'Users_Model_Book')
        ->addComponent('br', 'Users_Model_BookRating')
        ->update('b')
        ->set('b.bookrating', 'ROUND(SUM(br.rating) / COUNT(br.id)')
        ->where('b.id = ' . (bool) $this->id);
    echo $q->getSqlQuery();
```

Will return **SELECT b.id AS b_*id, br.id AS br*_id FROM b WHERE b.id = 1**

Anybody that can help me?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Update is almost never used, you have fully functional `save` method that will do that for you.

Comment: Update if a very common function to do. Why should I first select something to be able to update it?

Comment: Because it is simpler :)
Anyway: you have Doctrine_Collection::save() method that would update all loaded objects within single transaction. If something went wrong, DB would be reverted to previous state. I made a program that updates about 600.000 rows in less than a second. How? I have no idea but it simply works.

Try to pick simpler solution first. Doctrine is awesome, you should use all it provides.